# RuntimeError: Function 'SqrtBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output with l1 regularisation

Tags: python, runtime-error, torch, loss, sqrt

I am trying to implement a loss function as the one described in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt84X.png). My problem is that when I add the L1 regularization term, I encounter the following error message :

> RuntimeError: Function 'SqrtBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.

I have tried different codes to calculate L1 norm of matrix L :

```
(torch.sign(L[:, idx[0], idx[1]])*L[:, idx[0], idx[1]]).sum(dim=1).mean()
tmp[:, idx[0], idx[1]].abs().sum(dim = 1).mean()
torch.linalg.norm(tmp[:, idx[0], idx[1]], dim = 1).mean()
torch.linalg.vector_norm(tmp[:, idx[0], idx[1]], dim = 1, ord = 1).mean()
```

I have coded the rest of the loss function as follows : `- net.likelihood.log_prob(batch).mean() + 0.001 * net.kld_() + 0.01 * (F.mse_loss(batch, mu) ** 2).mean()`

This part of the loss doesn't have any problem, the training does fine with it.

However, I keep on having the mistake quoted above when I add the L1 norm. I believe this originates from the abs() function, which can also be formulated as sqrt(x²). There is a problem during the `loss.backward()` with the derivative of this function.

I have researched on stackoverflow and seen numerous encounter of this problem, but none with the abs() function. I wanted to know if anyone would have some piece of information about this error ?

Thanks in advance !